# php changed database date value

Tags: php, mysql, date

review this piece of code:

```
$values = $mysqli->query("select * from `my_table`");
while($value = $values->fetch_array()) {
   print_array($value);
}
```

however one column having a date structure does this:

```
[8] => 2016-11-20
[date] => 2016-10-02 15:52:18
```

As you can see, 8 is having a different value as date however, they should be the same value because it is the same column in the same row.
How can 'date' be changed?

the expected result = 2016-11-20 because that is the same value as stored in my database

info about my table:
it has 8 different columns containing all kind of things that do work. the 8th field is named 'date' and has type 'DATE'

concluding: somehow my output is in datetime (wrong time and date though) while it should be DATE

Comment: @RazibAlMamun that is not possible, because $value is only set IN the while loop

Comment: sorry my missed

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: 2016-11-20 is expected

Comment: what type of column is it? can you do `DESCRIBE my_table` and paste the output to your question please ?

Comment: `8` and  `date` your column name. right?

Comment: @DuaneLortie Edited. razibalmanun yes

Comment: why you used column name `8`? i thinks this is your problem

Comment: @RazibAlMamun this is done by the fetch array function.

Comment: can you try `echo $value['8'];`

Comment: @RazibAlMamun thanks for trying to help but you are not quite up to date regarding this matter i believe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128482/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-mart-haarman).

Comment: 8 is just the numerical index of the array, from column 8 of the database..  echoing it *SHOULD* be no different than using the column name, but in this case it is different.. leading me to my conclusion in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of MySQL, there seems to be some ambiguity (to me at least) about the "DATE" column type. From your results it appears that DATE is an alias for DATETIME, but MySQL does some truncation on the result.

So, a work around..  Don't user * , instead specify your column names , and on column 8, use the DATE function to retrieve only the date portion.

```
select `col1`, `col2`, ..., DATE(`col8`) from `my_table`");
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid of me but yeah, was gathering data from multiple tables